# Visualizing Tunnel mapping with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d, arcscene

I have a cluod point of a tunnel from indoor laser scanner. Are ther any features to create nice 3d simulation / visualisation / animation of it that will includ grid at surface like in the attached picture ?
[image: Tunel]

Of course any suggestion wil be halpfull not only ESRI's tools.

[image: tunnel2]

Comment: What software was used to produce the images you included in your question?

Comment: I don't know, its from here - http://www.controlsystem.ca/?3d-tunnel-control,10

Answer (score 2):

This will not be mych of an answer; You may be able to "sort of" visualize an already finished mesh in ArcScene you will definitely NOT be able to create it in ArcGIS. I don't have much experience with 3D AutoCAD but its likely possible with some autodesk / plugin product.

I've used a fantastic software called Leapfrog Mining in the past to model complex subsurface 3D meshes. I've done all sorts of 3D modelling and interpolations with this software but i've never tried interpolating any data similar to what you have.  Unfortunately, I no longer use the software because it is extremaly expensive and only a subscription based.  Still, you can check out the interpolating options here: http://www.leapfrog3d.com/products/leapfrog-geo/features/interpolating-data

Contact Leapfrog with any questions, the customer support is good.  They also have other products; Hydro, Geo (a new generation version of mining), geothermal and a free viewer. I cannot stress how fantastic and polished this software is but price is very steep. (Setting up animations and flyovers is very easy and a features included in the software )

Another option may be GEMS, specifically [GEMS Underground](http://www.geovia.com/node/5391#mine-design-underground). Again, I used core GEMS software for resource modelling but not for interpolation and visualization of tunel/cave surveys.  It is my understanding GEMS has mine tunnel design modules so you may be able to visualize.

Also found this on the internet which has some interesting info and links:
http://vterrain.org/Elevation/Caves/